# First differences filter

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

I am beginning in signal processing and my professor is asking me to do a first differences filter to my timeserie. I know I am supposed to use the filter() function but I don't know what numerator (b) and denominator (a) coefficient vectors am I supposed to use. Is first differences and first-order the same ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you should read up on [Matlab's documentation of the filter function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/filter.html).  If you just want to take a first difference, what you're looking to generate is the series:

```
1 * y(n) = 1 * x(n) - 1 * x(n - 1)
```

Which corresponds to the vector a = 1, and b = [1, -1], so your Matlab code would look like:

```
y = filter([1,-1],1,x);
```

Comment: Is it the same thing as an autoregressive moving average ?

Comment: Here, notice we are generating y(n) as a function of x(n), x(n-1).  In an autoregressive process, one generates x(n+1) as a function of lagged values.

Comment: Than you Prototoast. When I plot the spectrum, both reduce significantly the noise floor. The first difference filter will totally flat the fft(white) while the ARMA keep some power in the low frequency(more red). I am wondering which one is fit the real spectrum the best.

Comment: That sort of depends on the properties of the "real" spectrum.  There is no one "right" answer.

Comment: What do you mean by property of the real spectrum ? noise distribution?